# How to detect virtual buttons (Android 4)?

Tags: android, button, android-4.0-ice-cream-sandwich

I would like to detect if the phone running my Android application uses hardware buttons or virtual buttons (Galaxy Nexus).

Is there a way to get this information?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since API level 14 you can use [ViewConfiguration.hasPermanentMenuKey()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewConfiguration.html#hasPermanentMenuKey%28%29) to detect if a device has a permanent menu key.

Generally, virtual and physical buttons are mutually exclusive, so this would help you. Example:

```
public class MyActivity extends Activity {

    // ...
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        boolean hasPermanentMenuKey = ViewConfiguration.get(this).hasPermanentMenuKey();
        boolean hasVirtualKeys = !hasPermanentMenuKey;
        String message = hasVirtualKeys ? "This device has virtual menu keys" : "This device has physical keys";
        Toast.makeText(this, message, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
    // ...

}
```

**WARNING**: There are some cases in which this won't help you. For example, say a manufacturer decides to use virtual keys along with physical menu keys; then this method wouldn't help you. Another case would be if the phone has no virtual keys and no physical menu key (e.g. Samsung S5).

Comment: `ViewConfiguration.hasPermanentMenuKey()`  returns false on Samsung S5 but the phone has no virtual keys. I don't think this is a proper way to check for virtual keys any longer.

Comment: You're right. The S5 has no physical menu key but has no virtual buttons either, so `boolean hasVirtualKeys = !hasPermanentMenuKey;` is no longer valid. I've updated my answer with a warning regarding this.